# Como hacer para que un endpoint no me exija el token en Django?

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework, jwt, tokens

estoy realizando un proyecto con Django Rest y simple-jwt. Por default en `setting.py` especifiqué lo siguiente:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ("rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",),
}
```

Así que todas las vistas están protegidas por token. Pero quiero hacer algunas excepciones y dejar algunos endpoints públicos.

Intenté colocando en esas vistas específicas lo siguiente:

```
authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
```

pero cuando hago la petición me aparece el siguiente error incluso colocando el token:

```json
{
    "detail": "Las credenciales de autenticación no se proveyeron."
}
```

Luego intente poniendo en `views.py`

```
authentication_classes = []
```

Y este es el error:

```json
{
    "detail": "Usted no tiene permiso para realizar esta acción."
}
```

Que tendría que hacer para que no me pida autenticación de ningún tipo?

Comment: Cuando en postman estamos nuevos , empezamos a realizar pruebas con el superusuario al que aun no hemos otorgado permisos, asi que cuando realizamos un GET y ya hemos creado el login , el necesita validar y como no hemos dado ningun permiso, pues aparece el error. me paso, le di permisos al super usuario y listo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente debes importar permissions y en la clase del endpoint debes poner AllowAny:

```
from rest_framework import permissions
```

Y luego

```
permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
```

Se usa sobre todo por ejemplo para los logins que obviamente no se va a tener token para enviar, un saludo

Comment: Excelente, solucionó el problema. Había visto esa clase en el código fuente de rest_framework, pero no pensé que cambiar los permisos iba a afectar al método de autenticación. Muchísimas gracias.